# Error deploying with Netlify-cli in GitLab CI: Cannot find module netlify-cli/scripts/postinstall.js’

Tags: reactjs, deployment, gitlab-ci, gatsby, netlify

I'm trying to deploy my Gatsby website to Netlify as the last step of my **GitLab CI/CD pipeline**, and I get "*Cannot find module netlify-cli/scripts/postinstall.js*" error during the deployment process.

Error trace:

```
 $ npx netlify-cli deploy --site $NETLIFY_SITE_ID --auth $NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN --prod
 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023
   throw err;
   ^
 Error: Cannot find module '/root/.npm/_npx/36/lib/node_modules/netlify-cli/scripts/postinstall.js'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1020:15)
 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:890:27)
 at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
 at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: []
 }
```

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml configuration:

```
image: node:latest

cache:
  untracked: true
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - build
  - deploy


build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - ./node_modules/.bin/gatsby build --prefix-paths
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm i -g netlify-cli
    - npx netlify-cli deploy --site $NETLIFY_SITE_ID --auth $NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN --prod
  dependencies:
    - build
  only:
    - master
```

**Do you know how to solve this problem?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I was running "netlify-cli" instead "netlify":

It works:

```
npx netlify deploy --site $NETLIFY_SITE_ID --auth $NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN --prod
```

Comment: you can remove npm i -g netlify-cli. You don't need it when you use npx command. This will speed up your build a bit.

Comment: i've tried to remove it, but fails: netlify command not found